# Flush DDL Cache

Tags: magento-1.9, database, cache, upgrade-script

I created an update script to create some new fields in the database for my custom model. When I am trying to save the model the new fields are not being saved. I thing Magento caches the DDL information of the table.
Is there a way to **flush only that cache** instead of clearing all cache?
I tried with **`$connection->resetDdlCache();`** but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make DB structure changes in upgrade script?

Answer (score 1):

This is how Magento 2 clears its DDL cache during `setup:upgrade` process:

```
private function cleanDdlCache()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager $cacheManager */
    $cacheManager = $this->objectManagerProvider->get()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager::class);
    $cacheManager->clean([\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DdlCache::TYPE_IDENTIFIER]);
    $this->log->log('DDL cache cleared successfully');
}
```

You can use the same code (and may be a few modifications) to programmatically clear DDL cache **OR**

Use CLI to run `magento cache:flush(or clean) db_ddl`.

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to disable all of the caches and then reenable them?

P/s: I was able to get it fixed the last time by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to reply :)
here is how I clean DDL cache for one table in Magento 1.9 using a custom script :

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/PATH_TO/app/Mage.php');

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('MODULE/MODEL');

$key = sprintf('%s_%s_%s', Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::DDL_CACHE_PREFIX,$tableName, Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::DDL_DESCRIBE);
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();
$cache->remove($key);
```